# Error al intentar crear una base de datos

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito crear una base de datos con estos datos, sin embargo al introducir la tabla PRESTAMO me da un error.
No tengo gran conocimiento sobre mysql por lo que me ayudaría mucho si veis el codigo que se me ha proporicionado y como tengo que crear la base de datos. Porque cuando tengo creadas todas las tablas y intento crear la de PRESTAMO me da el siguiente error:

```
CREATE TABLE PRESTAMO ( 
  Codigo integer not null primary key,  
  Cod_Lector integer not null references lector,  
  ISBN varchar(10) not null,  
  Cod_Suc integer not null,  
  Fecha_Ini date not null,  
  Fecha_Dev date, 
  foreign key (Cod_Suc, ISBN) references dispone (Cod_Suc, ISBN) );
```

> **ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint**

Les adjunto el archivo de creaccion de la base de datos. (los comandos que he utilizado)

```
CREATE TABLE EDITORIAL (
Codigo integer not null primary key, 
Nombre varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE LIBRO (
ISBN varchar(10) not null primary key, 
Titulo varchar(60) not null, 
Ano_Edicion integer, 
Cod_Editorial integer not null references editorial
);

CREATE TABLE NACIONALIDAD (
Codigo integer not null primary key, 
Nombre varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE AUTOR (
Codigo integer not null primary key, 
Nombre varchar(50), 
Apellido varchar (50),
Ano_Nac integer, 
Ano_Fall integer, 
Cod_Nacion  integer references nacionalidad
);


CREATE TABLE ESCRIBE (
ISBN varchar(10) not null references libro, 
Cod_Autor integer not null references autor,
primary key (ISBN, Cod_Autor)
);

CREATE TABLE SUCURSAL (
Codigo integer not null primary key, 
Direccion varchar(50),
Poblacion varchar(50), 
Provincia varchar (15) 
);

CREATE TABLE DISPONE (
Cod_Suc integer not null references sucursal,  
ISBN varchar(10) not null references libro, 
Num_Ejemplares integer, 
Num_Disponibles integer,
primary key (Cod_Suc, ISBN),
check (Num_Disponibles <= Num_Ejemplares AND Num_Disponibles >=0 AND Num_Ejemplares >=0)
);

CREATE TABLE LECTOR (
Codigo integer not null primary key, 
Nombre varchar(20), 
Ape_1 varchar(20), 
Ape_2 varchar(20), 
Direccion varchar(50), 
Poblacion varchar(50), 
Provincia varchar (15), 
Fecha_Nac date
);


CREATE TABLE PRESTAMO (
Codigo integer not null primary key, 
Cod_Lector integer not null references lector, 
ISBN varchar(10) not null, 
Cod_Suc integer not null, 
Fecha_Ini date not null, 
Fecha_Dev date,
foreign key (Cod_Suc, ISBN) references dispone(Cod_Suc, ISBN)
);
```

ACTUALIZO: Os dejo una foto para que veáis que la tabla DISPONE esta creada y aun así no puedo crear la tabla préstamo.
[image]

Comment: Traté de reproducir el error en [este SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed730a), pero el código se ejecuta correctamente.

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es que cuando intentaste crear la tabla PRESTAMO, aún no creabas la tabla DISPONE, y por eso te marcó el error

Comment: tu tabla no tiene una llave primaria para hacer la relacion, debes crear la llave primariara para luego usarla en tu siguiente tabla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta ya la obtuve.

Gracias al comentario de Luis Cazares que en esa página de sql todo funcionaba correctamente logre ver cual era el **quit** de la cuestión.

> Resulta que al crear la tabla `PRESTAMO` lo hacia correctamente en la página web, entonces me di cuenta que al cambiar el dispone de la `foreign key` que se estaba creando a mayúsculas podía solucionar el fallo y así fue de esa forma se solucionó cree la tabla y ya tengo la base de datos funcionando.